# Have we found any Venusian meteorites?

Tags: venus, meteorite

Many [Martian meteorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_meteorite) have been found on Earth. It also is possible for [Earth rocks to have landed on Mars](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36415/9527). So I guess it would also be possible for meteorites on Earth to come from Venus. Have any such meteorites been found? Would it indeed be possible to find Venusian meteorites on Earth?

Martian meteorites are recognizable because we know the composition of the atmosphere of Mars. Do we know the composition of the Venusian atmosphere well enough for this purpose?
If we found a Venusian meteorite, would we be able to recognize it as such?

Comment: Hope not, seeing as Venusian ejecta is most likely protomolecule.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft What do you mean by "Venusian ejecta is most likely protomolecule"?

Comment: @usernumber   see James S.A.Corey  "The Expanse" series.   #itsajoke